# Import problem with PyCrypto in Jython

Tags: python, jython, pycrypto

I am currently trying to get python bittorrent tracker running inside of jython and i encountered this problem:
the tracker uses PyCrypto library which i compiled for my platform and added into the python path. When i try to run code, however, i get following error:

```
Exception in thread "MainThread" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python_dep/BitTorrent-5.2.2/bittorrent-tracker.py", line 21, in <module>
    from BitTorrent.track import track
  File "./python_dep/BitTorrent-5.2.2/BitTorrent/track.py", line 50, in <module>
    from BitTorrent.UI import Size
  File "./python_dep/BitTorrent-5.2.2/BitTorrent/UI.py", line 37, in <module>
    from BitTorrent.MultiTorrent import UnknownInfohash, TorrentAlreadyInQueue, TorrentAlreadyRunning, TorrentNotRunning
  File "./python_dep/BitTorrent-5.2.2/BitTorrent/MultiTorrent.py", line 25, in <module>
    from BitTorrent.Torrent import Feedback, Torrent
  File "./python_dep/BitTorrent-5.2.2/BitTorrent/Torrent.py", line 32, in <module>
    from BitTorrent.ConnectionManager import ConnectionManager
  File "./python_dep/BitTorrent-5.2.2/BitTorrent/ConnectionManager.py", line 22, in <module>
    from BitTorrent.Connector import Connector
  File "./python_dep/BitTorrent-5.2.2/BitTorrent/Connector.py", line 27, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
ImportError: cannot import name ARC4
Java Result: 1
```

I am pretty sure that the library is in the python path, because command

```
import Crypto.Cipher
```

works, while

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
```

does not. 
The java code i run looks like this:

```
package jythTest;
```

import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         PythonInterpreter pythonInterpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
         pythonInterpreter.exec("import sys");


         pythonInterpreter.exec("sys.path.append(\"./python_dep/BitTorrent-5.2.2/\")");
         pythonInterpreter.exec("sys.path.append(\"./python_dep/Twisted-10.0.0/\")");
         pythonInterpreter.exec("sys.path.append(\"./python_dep/Zope-3.4.0/build/lib.linux-i686-2.6\")");
         pythonInterpreter.exec("sys.path.append(\"./python_dep\")");
         pythonInterpreter.exec("sys.path.append(\"./python_dep/pycrypto-2.0.1/build/lib.linux-i686-2.6\")");
         pythonInterpreter.exec("sys.path.append(\"import Crypto.Cipher\")");

         //pythonInterpreter.exec("print sys.path");
         pythonInterpreter.execfile("./python_dep/BitTorrent-5.2.2/bittorrent-tracker.py");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who could provide any kind of help.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening probably because pycrypto is a C-extension, and Jython will not be able to call it without a Java wrapper for this extension.

Comment: hmm but other C extensions seems to be working fine. Also, it is able to call the module itself, just won't call the functions

Comment: What extensions ? Maybe ARC4 is the extension and the Crypto.Cipher is just a Python wrapper in pure-python.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this applies to your situation, but some googling led to this:

(from http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/InstallingJython)

> Jython cannot find your Java class,
>   even though it exists in the class
>   path. This shows up as "ImportError:
>   cannot import name xxx" or
>   "AttributeError: java package xxx' has
>   no attribute 'yyy'"
>
> This happens when Jython is installed
>   as a Java extension (i.e. when
>   jython.jar is installed in
>   java\jre\lib\ext) and your classes
>   are installed in the classpath.
>
> The reason is Java extensions can only
>   see other extensions, not other
>   classes defined in the CLASSPATH or
>   passed in to java using the
>   --classpath option.
>
> There are two ways to fix this:
>
> 1) Move your classes to the
>   java\jre\lib\ext directory.
>
> 2) Remove jython.jar from the
>   java\jre\lib\ext directory and put
>   jython.jar in the CLASSPATH or use the
>   java --classpath option.
>
> (from the Jython-users mailing list)

And another, similar issue, but different nonetheless:

(from http://bugs.jython.org/issue1878866)

> I have a similar problem in Linux with jython 2.5. Inside
>   jython2.5.0/Lib/site-packages a have a foo directory where there is a
>   Java class (Bar.class) and a jython class (BarPy.py). i have also put an
>   empty __init__.py file. In the jython interpreter environment I can
>   always import Bar like this: "from foo import Bar" however I cannot
>   import BarPy. If I delete the java class from the directory then I can
>   import the jython script

Comment: interesting, i don't have jython installed as java extension though, i just generated standalone lib jar and added it to the project